# Create random encoded password, but send clear version to user

Tags: php, symfony, security

I'm currently developing a website on which I want to generate a random password for each user, and then encode it to keep it in the database.

But, I also want to be able to retrieve the decoded password to either send it by email to the user, or giving it to him by another way unrelated to the site itself (by phone, skype or whatever)

I'm using Symfony with the bcrypt algorithm for encoding, using the default UserPasswordEncoder.

Is there any way to access the decoded password, or should I keep both plainPassword (for sending) and encodedPassword (for authenticating) in my database? If I do so, is there any security risk knowing that the plain password would not be modifiable or accesible by the website in itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping clear passwords is **always** a bad idea. To react to your post:

- Keeping in your database a clear password alongside the encoded one is useless. The point of having a hashed password in the first place is to prevent the clear password to be accessed. Security-wise, it is exactly the same as not encoding the password at all.
- You don't want to keep clear passwords. Never keep clear passwords. It is always a security risk, as proven by the countless data leaks of the recent years.
- Don't send passwords by mail. This is bad practice, as anybody gaining access to your user mailbox will have access to your service at the same time.
- For support purposes, you want a way to generate a new password for the user rather than accessing the one previously defined. This way, you keep being able to help the user while retaining good security. You would in this case send the password to the user at the time it is generated, store a hashed version in the database, and enforce a mandatory password change when the user logs in to ensure that the password in the mailbox can't later be used to gain access to your service. Alternatively, even better, you can also give the user a token allowing him to reset his password himself.

If you **really** want to keep passwords in clear (once again, **don't do it**), you want at the very least to encode it using strong encryption (such as RSA), and retain for yourself the private key enabling you (and only you) to decode the password while keeping a secure version in the database.

Cryptographic hash algorithms, which are usually used to encode passwords (such as PBKDF2) are specially used to avoid retrieving the password in clear. For you, or anyone else.

Comment: I unfortunately have to send it by mail, but I will stay away from keeping clear password in database. I consider it bad practice as well, it's just that it's a website I have to rebuild, and it's how it's done actually, I imagine it's for a reason; but if there is no way to backtrack from encoded to clear password with bcrypt, like you can with RSA, I will just change the website logic. Thank you all for your answers

Comment: Push back on your requirement of having to send it over email, and point to this post when you're told no, and then push back again.

Answer (score 0):

Password that can be recovered is NOT a password. Always keep user passwords hashed and generate a new one when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can not decrypt password when you encrypt it with bcrypy if you really need plain passwords store it in database, but its really bad idea.

Explanaton: One way algorithms like bcrypt can not be decoded. Storing plain passwords in database is evil. If someone hacks your database or you will have some exploit for example sql injection, bad guy can get all your user passwords. There is some stories with big companies in old times who stored passwords in plain, they got really precious lessons when they got hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the clear password would make the crypted one useless, don't do that.

Sending the clear password can be possible, when you generate the random string to create the password, then you an send it at this moment.

But the best thing to do is to force the user to create a new password